# Eclipse 3.3 Europa JDT TextHover

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt

I want to show my own text hover in eclipse for some specific words? Please provide me some examples

Comment: Any particular reason you're using 3.3 Europa? 3.4 Ganymede is nearly a year old, and we're approaching the release of 3.5 Galileo.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by looking at [Koder examples](http://www.koders.com/?s=ITextHover&p=).

E.g. this  [CEditorTextHoverDispatcher](http://www.koders.com/java/fid530207B6126EC285990C517DEBCC5726EDF6B98E.aspx?s=ITextHover#L11) or this  [UCTextHover](http://www.koders.com/java/fidC066F0660105FB8FF130D12AD233B6B6BD9E44FD.aspx?s=ITextHover#L15)

```
package com.ut2003.uceditor;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.IRegion;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextHover;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Region;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;

public class UCTextHover implements ITextHover
{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Method declared on ITextHover
     */
    public String getHoverInfo(ITextViewer textViewer, IRegion hoverRegion)
    {
        if (hoverRegion != null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (hoverRegion.getLength() > -1)
                    return textViewer.getDocument().get(hoverRegion.getOffset(), hoverRegion.getLength());
            }
            catch (BadLocationException x)
            {
            }
        }
        return "Empty Selection";
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * Method declared on ITextHover
     */
    public IRegion getHoverRegion(ITextViewer textViewer, int offset)
    {
        Point selection = textViewer.getSelectedRange();
        if (selection.x <= offset && offset < selection.x + selection.y)
            return new Region(selection.x, selection.y);
        return new Region(offset, 0);
    }
}
```

---

You would set a TextHover in a `SourceViewerConfiguration` like this  [`GasSourceViewerConfiguration`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid441801AFBF843A71F77B2AD1DCF4FE3FEED01A64.aspx?s=ITextHover#L20) or this [`CalcSourceViewerConfiguration`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid7881D97684780311E7421E2E078A43DF10815CCE.aspx?s=ITextHover#L9)

```
package com.example.calc.ui.editors;

import org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextHover;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.IReconciler;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISourceViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration;

/**
 * @author cdaly
 *
 * To change the template for this generated type comment go to
 * Window&gt;Preferences&gt;Java&gt;Code Generation&gt;Code and Comments
 */
public class CalcSourceViewerConfiguration extends SourceViewerConfiguration {

    private CalcEditor _editor;

    public CalcSourceViewerConfiguration(CalcEditor editor){
        _editor = editor;
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration#getReconciler(org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISourceViewer)
     */
    public IReconciler getReconciler(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
        return new MonoReconciler(_editor.getReconcilingStrategy(), false);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration#getTextHover(org.eclipse.jface.text.source.ISourceViewer, java.lang.String)
     */
    public ITextHover getTextHover(
        ISourceViewer sourceViewer,
        String contentType) {
        ITextHover hover;
        if (_editor != null && _editor instanceof CalcEditor) {
            hover = new CalcTextHover((CalcEditor)_editor);
        } else {
            hover = null;
        }
        return hover;
    }

}
```

---

Beyond that, I have not much more information: the examples I have found are more programmatic than declarative (i.e. "`plugin.xml`"), so you may want to explore some more code.

Another good example: [Eclipse: Rich Hovers Redux](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2009/05/eclipse-rich-hovers-redux/) (it is for eclipse3.4 though, but the full example can give you another hint at how a custom ITextHover is added to the current editor)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Which wizard should i take in the eclipse plugin development environment to add this hover in JavaEditor? Which extension point should I add in plugin.xml to get this in JavaEditor

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to use the java editor plugin along with eclipse first. Take eclipse help ->welcome->Samples->Java Editor plugin